# Vbscript Move Files and Copy Structure of folders 90 days old or more than Now

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript, administration

Im looking to traverse  folders on a share, copy entire structure if the folders or subfolders contain files older than 90 days. (move files older than said days-copy structure if folders contain said aged files)

Ive got a script I found online, ive altered it to actualy use the DateAdd function correctly and it seems to move the files over but it doesnt copy the structure.

Example.

2 Share locations containing files (this isnt the exact structure but mearly an example)

```
Source
1. \\Share1\folder
2.         \Folder\Files
3.                \Folder\Files
4.         \Folder

1. \\Share2\folder
2.         \Folder\Files
3.                \Folder\Files
4.         \Folder
Destination
1. \\Share2\folder
2.         \Folder\Files
3.                \Folder\Files
4.         \Folder

1. \\Share2\folder
2.         \Folder\Files
3.                \Folder\Files
4.         \Folder
```

---

```
Dim objFSO, ofolder, objStream

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set outfile = fso.createtextfile("Move-Result.txt",true)
SPath = "Y:\test"
Sdest = "Y:\Archive\"

ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder(spath)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
CheckFolder(subfolder)
ShowSubFolders Subfolder
Next
End Sub

'CheckFolder(objFSO.getFolder(SPath))

Sub CheckFolder(objCurrentFolder)
Dim strTempL, strTempR, strSearchL, strSearchR, objNewFolder, objFile
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
currDate = Date
dtmDate = DateAdd("d",-90,Now)
strTargetDate = ConvDate(dtmDate)
For Each objFile In objCurrentFolder.Files
FileName = objFile
'WScript.Echo FileName
'strDate = ConvDate(objFile.DateCreated)
strDate = ConvDate(objFile.DateLastModified)
If strDate < strTargetDate Then
objFSO.MoveFile FileName, Sdest
outfile.writeline Filename
End If
Next
End Sub

Function ConvDate (sDate) 'Converts MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS to string YYYYMMDD
strModifyDay = day(sDate)
If len(strModifyDay) < 2 Then
strModifyDay = "0" & strModifyDay
End If
strModifyMonth = Month(sDate)
If len(strModifyMonth) < 2 Then
strModifyMonth = "0" & strModifyMonth
End If
strModifyYear = Year(sDate)
ConvDate = strModifyYear & strModifyMonth & strModifyDay
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class for handling file synchronization a while back that you are welcome to adapt to your needs.

here is the link to the documentation for the [Primary Class](http://hetland.ws/blog/synchronization-class-reference/) And the [Individual File Object Class](http://hetland.ws/blog/synchronization-class-reference/syncfile-reference/)

At the bottom of the page there is a button to view/save the source code labeled "Active Development Branch"

Including that class in your project you could then accomplish your goal like so.

```
Dim oSyncAgent, sUpdateSource, sUpdateTarget, dMinAge, aStagedAFiles, iIterator
Set oSyncAgent = New SynchronizationAgent

sUpdateSource = "Y:\test"
sUpdateTarget = "Y:\Archive"
dMinAge = DateAdd("d",-90,Now)

'This will only proceed if the SetLocations() function is successful
If oSyncAgent.SetLocations(sUpdateSource,sUpdateTarget) Then

  'Get a working copy of the files staged for sync from location A to B
  aStagedAFiles = oSyncAgent.LocationAStaged

  'Loop over files staged for synchronization and cancel any that were created in the last 90 days
  For iIterator = 0 To UBound(aStagedAFiles)
    If aStagedAFiles(iIterator).DateCreated >= dMinAge Then
      aStagedAFiles(iIterator).Process = False
    End If
  Next 'SyncFile

  'Set the modified list of files to be synced back to the agent
  oSyncAgent.LocationAStaged = aStagedAFiles

  'Execute the sync ignoring the files we set above
  oSyncAgent.AbSync(False) 'Don't mirror location A

End If

Set oSyncAgent = Nothing
```

Comment: thanks for the response, didnt think anyone was going to respond. Im getting the following (9, 8) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Invalid 'exit' statement http://hetland.ws/blog/synchronizationagent-class-reference/

Comment: In the example it assumes this is within a function. it is the "Exit Function" line that is throwing the error, If you are running this in a global context and wanted to die you could use WScript.Exit() instead. I've edited the code example to change the way it checks if it should proceed